# Run an ubuntu process only if a computer is online

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping, daemon

I have a systemd process in Ubuntu that I only need running when a PC on the network is online (It's a status monitor app). I thought about using another service that pings the NetBIOS name, but I can't figure out how to implement it

Comment: Lately, the question descriptions have gotten too short. Yours is two and a half lines long on our displays. We could start writing a few guidelines in this direction, but it is simply too soon. Can you first try something on your own?

Comment: The problem is I don't know where to start, thats why I'm asking

Comment: Yes, but people generally start striving a little bit before asking. Try writing a simple _Bourne-Again_ Shell-Script that pings a machine and checks the result of the ping in a loop.

Comment: Now what? @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: Can you take a look at [this article](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/ping-a-list-of-computers-and-double-check-dns-name-against-netbios-name/)?

Comment: Ok, I did that now how do I make it turn a service on or  off @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: Your Issue is not trivial. You are attempting to join the _Unix_ Family of Operating Systems with the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Family of Operating Systems. For a tutorial related to the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Services, we would head toward [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer). Programming _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Services is _not_ trivial.

Comment: What the FUCK. I don't use Windows @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: You have asked us earlier "_how do I make it turn a service on or off_", @Javience. Are there any services in the "_Ubuntu_" Operating System?

Comment: Yes @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: If your question is _exclusively_ about the _Ubuntu_ Operating System, @Javience, then maybe it would have been better if you had asked it on the _Ask Ubuntu_ Web-Site. You can take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd) in order to get some pointers.

Comment: It is not specific to Ubuntu @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: Since you have stated on this Web-Page the fact that "_What the FUCK. I don't use Windows_", @Javience, then you could better head toward the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Web-Site and reach out there for help.

Comment: It is not specific to Unix & Linux, it relates to all. @DOBRESCU_Mihai